# Подскажите с регуляркой в .htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Сделал вот такой правило для подключения нужного языка(если задано) и собственно самой страницы:

```
RewriteRule ^(ua|ru|eng)?/?log/?$   index.php?module=Log&lang=$1  [L,QSA]
```

По такому правилу работают 3 ссылки:

1. site.com/log
2. site.com/ua/log
3. site.com/ualog

Как можете видеть, 3 вариант довольно странный и может вредить в SEO(но это не точно). Причиной работы 3 ссылки является знак вопроса `/?log`. Если убрать этот знак вопроса, то при таком правиле не будет работать 1 пункт из списка. Как оставить 1 и 2 пункт, но исключить 3?

Comment: `((ua|ru|eng)?/)?log/?$` такой вариант не сработает? Только если сработает `lang=$2`, Ну или если регулярное выражение позволит, то можно сделать первую группу не захватываемой `(?:(ua|ru|eng)?/)?log/?$`

Comment: @PotroNik , можете добавить как ответ 1 вариант, отмечу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант попробовать использовать дополнительную необязательную группу

```
((ua|ru|eng)?/)?log/?$
```

в данном случае будет изменена группа подставляемая lang на вторую и нужно будет использовать `lang=$2`

В дополнительной группе условие  обязательное наличие `/`, т.е. совпадения не произойдет в случае если будет ualog.